# angularjs hide/show add button after saving/create

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to hide **"add new button"** when Im creating the record. and only show it back when Im done creating record.

Same as the ***"submit one button"***, I want to hide it (submit one button) and showing back the ***"add new button"*** as Im done submitting. How to do that?

below is my code and here is my ***[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1c8f2LiTiM8G1dC47Hpl?p=preview)***:

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularjs-starter">

  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom Plunker</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
      document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <a ng-show="hideAddButton" ng-hide="hideAddButton" ng-click="addNew();hideAddButton = !hideAddButton">+ add new</a>
    <form name="mainForm" ng-submit="submitAll()">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-form="subForm">          
          <input type="text" required name="name" ng-model="item.name"/>
          <span ng-show="subForm.name.$error.required">required</span>
          <button type="button" ng-disabled="subForm.$invalid" ng-click="submitOne(item);hideAddButton = !hideAddButton">Submit One</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button type="submit" ng-disabled="mainForm.$invalid">Submit All</button>
    </form>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-show="lastSubmit">Last Submit:</div>
    <pre>{{lastSubmit | json}}</pre>
  </body>

</html>
```

***app.js***

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.addNew = function (){
    $scope.items.push({ name: '' });
  };

  $scope.submitOne = function (item){
    $scope.lastSubmit = angular.copy(item);
  };

  $scope.submitAll = function() {
    $scope.lastSubmit = angular.copy($scope.items);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:  http://plnkr.co/edit/8kOmWQ96UFkNOxZqcFMS?p=preview

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.isSubmitting = false;
  $scope.addNew = function (){
    $scope.isSubmitting = true;
   // Here I added a state for each item. 
    $scope.items.push({ name: '', showButton:true }); 
  };

  $scope.submitOne = function (item){
    item.showButton = false; 
    $scope.isSubmitting = false;
    $scope.lastSubmit = angular.copy(item);
  };

  $scope.submitAll = function() {
    $scope.items.forEach(function(i){i.showButton=false;})
    $scope.isSubmitting = false;
    $scope.lastSubmit = angular.copy($scope.items);
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<a ng-hide="isSubmitting" ng-click="addNew();">+ add new</a>
<form name="mainForm" ng-submit="submitAll()">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-form="subForm">          
      <input type="text" required name="name" ng-model="item.name"/>
      <span ng-show="subForm.name.$error.required">required</span>
      <button ng-show="item.showButton" type="button" ng-disabled="subForm.$invalid" ng-click="submitOne(item);">Submit One</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button type="submit" ng-disabled="mainForm.$invalid">Submit All</button>
</form>
<hr/>
<div ng-show="lastSubmit">Last Submit:</div>
<pre>{{lastSubmit | json}}</pre>
</body>
```

I *think* this is what you are asking for, but I don't think the "submit all" button makes much sense in this scenario, unless you allow to add more items before submitting them (but you clearly state you want the "add new"-button hidden).

Also I was unsure if you actually wanted to store a state for each item, but showing/hiding all buttons didn't make much sense to me either...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) or [`ng-hide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) directives.

with ng-show:
`<button ng-show="hideAddButton === false">`

with ng-hide:
`<button ng-hide="hideAddButton === true">`

Comment: can you give an example in [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1c8f2LiTiM8G1dC47Hpl?p=preview)